# After Click, Multiple Elements Changing Attributes in CSS and HTML using Pseudo Selector

Tags: html, css, target, css-animations, pseudo-class

Right so, the idea is that after an element on a webpage is clicked, **multiple, unique** elements change their CSS attributes, (which could be, say, a CSS3 animation).

So, this code works, in the sense that, when the selector is clicked, it will change the text to red

```
<style type="text/css">
p {
    font-size:20px;
    }

p:target {
    color:red;
    }

#selector{
    font-size:20px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="selector"><a href="#one">Click here to change text to red</a></p>

<p id="one"> This text will change to red </p>
</body>
```

But you see, what I would like to happen is that another div could also change to red when the first selector is clicked. I can't work out a way to do this.

What I really want to be able to do is when the user clicks a button, multiple CSS3 animations are set off.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `jQuery`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/maxinacube/yRTZQ/).

jQuery can handle your animations cross-browser as well. [api.jquery.com/animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that for now, but I knew normally, that this is accomplished through the use of JavaScript.

The downside to using that is that I guess there are several resources at work all kinda adding to the client download and subtracting from the speed of the page.

I thought that with CSS3 there might be an easier and simpler solution.